# Constraints that changes depending on the device bounds in storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

Is it possible to create `constraints` (top , leading,trailing, bottom) that changes their constants depending on the device `width` and `height` using only `Storyboard` ?

**PS:** I don't want to add any additional `views` only to calculate the proper new `constraint`

Comment: yes you can do this.First you need to set the view's constants same as the superview(i.e. window) then you just need to change the multiplier varying from 0.1 to 1.0. Hope this will help to achieve what you want

Comment: Can you give more explanations ? What do you mean by set the view's constants same as the superview.

Comment: are you looking to achieve relative spacing between views?

Comment: Yes , I want to change spacing according to device's bounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of a hacky way of doing this, I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can space the view relatively by setting the position of the top of the view relative to the middle of the superview.

[image]

You have to use the multiplier, in order to do this and use the denominator as `(height of the canvas)/2`
The numerator can move between `0 - size of canvas` and it should position relative to the superview.

The same thing can be done to position it with regard to it's x axis.

You can play around with these values to maybe achieve what you're going for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i know this can resolve the problem but it's not what i am really looking for, i used this solution before and i find it very tricky.
I know every constraint conform to this formulas : A1 = A2 * M + C
so i want to create a constraint where :
- A1 : top attribut
- A2 : height attribut (of the superview)
- M : multiplier = 0.2
- C : constant = 0

Comment: Ah, I tried finding something similar -_-,  this was the best I could do, sorry friend.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has provided the size classes that automatically adjust constraints and updates views/constants according to the size of devices.

Please check your related question and its answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50111826/9532353)

Comment: I didn't understand how you choose the value of the multiplier for the label.

Comment: multiplier used if you want to do proportional layout. Eg. if you have superview(top, leading, trailing and bottom constraints) and you take subview in it with the half size of superview then your multiplier of subview width and height constraint will be 0.5 or 1:2. This will be work with any size of devices.

Comment: This was really helpful, but this solution doesn't work if the label was inside the view, and this is the most commun situation i found my self in, because otherwise i can always calculate the padding using the additional view you added, and that is what iam doing right now .

Answer (score 0):

Use **Size Classes** Concept

This has introduced in iOS 8

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I am aiming to reach is , for example : I want my top constraint to be equal to half the height of the super view.
I think with size class I need to provide a different constant for every class of device and that is not what I want to do.

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood your question.